# Firebase getUserByEmail doesn't return user information

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want get all user information by **getUserByEmail** function. But it's return **[object Object]**.

Maybe i do something wrong. I just need get user **displayName** and **photoURL** by user Email.

My Node.js

```
exports.getUserInfo = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    if (context.auth.token.admin !== true) {
        return {
            message: 'permission denied. Admin role require'
        }
    }
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
        .then(function (userRecord) {
            return {
                message: 'Successfully fetched user data:' + userRecord.toJSON()
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return {
                message: 'Error fetching user data:' + error
            }
        });
});
```

My Index.js

```
const updateForm = document.querySelector('#update-form');

updateForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email_st = document.querySelector('#update-email').value;

    const getUserInfo = functions.httpsCallable('getUserInfo');
    getUserInfo({
        email: email_st
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lii2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stringify the object to be able to print to console.

You can do so by following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

If you want to print it with some formatting, you can use-

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more details.